# JavaScript Fetch API - save text as object?

Tags: javascript, object, text, fetch-api

I am currently working with the fetch API in JavaScript. I have a text file I'd like to read from called sample.txt. I would like to grab the different lines out of the text file and save it in an array so I can work with it. I've been searching for how to save it as an object, but I think I've been using the code for JSON and not for text. Please give any suggestions?

sample.txt

```
apple
banana
orange
grape
```

index.js

```
let fruitArray; //initialized new array

fetch('sample.txt') // fetch text file
.then((resp) => resp.text())
.then(data.split(/\r?\n/) = fruitArray)) //tried to assign each separate line as an element of fruitArray
```

Expected Output

```
fruitArray = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grape'];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let fruitArray;` doesn't create a new array - you have to actually declare an array like `[]` for that. But it would be better to declare the array only once the response comes back, and then pass it around if needed.

`.then` accepts a *function* as a parameter, not a plain code block. The first parameter of the `.then` callback is the result of the resolution of the previous promise - which here is the full string.

When assigning (`=`), the left hand side needs to be a variable (or a property).

```
fetch('sample.txt') // fetch text file
  .then((resp) => resp.text())
  .then(data => {
    const fruitsArray = data.split(/\r?\n/);
  })
```

Comment: thank you! That did the trick. Do you know of any way to access the new fruitsArray outside of the fetch call?

Comment: You should call whatever function needs it with the parsed `fruitsArray`.